# How do I refer to dynamic range in google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

Here is my sheet:

```
     A       B            C
1    ID      VALUE        MY VAL
2    1        500         = AVERAGE(B2:B2)
3    2        400         = AVERAGE(B2:B3)
4    3        550         = AVERAGE(B2:B4)
5    4        700         = AVERAGE(B2:B5)
6    5       1200         = AVERAGE(B2:B6)
```

.......

This is a very long sheet so I can't input the `AVERAGE(B2:Bx)` manually. Is there any good ideas to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use an [absolute-relative reference](https://edu.gcfglobal.org/en/googlespreadsheets/types-of-cell-references/1/) like this:

`=average(B$2:B2)`